# use a href inside html entities

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I use `html entities` to secure my site.
And my client want to add link in his post using the CMS.
how to make exception in html entities?

my code example:

```
<p><?php echo h($row['message']) ?></p>
//h is my function for htmlentities
```

My code display this message:

```
"You can click this link <a href="###">Link</a>"
//And I dont know my data insert '\'
//It become <a href=\"###\">Link</a>
```

If my question is not clear please ask.
Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is pass into the DB with htmlentities() so it doesn't mess with your DB. To retrieve them you would use html_entity_decode(). The html_entity_decode() converts all strings with HTML entities back to there original string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Hopefully this answers your question.

Edit:
Raw data retrieved: `http://www.example.com`

Through htmlentities it spits out the HTML entities, which the browser cannot interpret when attempting to find that page. The use of `htmlentities()` (please if I'm wrong correct me) is to encode user input before passing it anywhere else.

User input: `<script>hacks</script>`

Passed though htmlentities:

```
&ltscript&gthacks&lt (whatever backslash is)script&gt
```

(This way it can't mess with anything in your database, better example is the use of PHP/MySQL but I'm not well versed to give that exact example at the moment.)

However this would expose your site when decoding it as well and other precautions would have to be taken.

Comment: I don't pass the data use htmlentities into the database. the database data still raw. I use htmlentities when retrieve the data from database. Is it possible to make exception to htmlentities?

Comment: I don't think you need htmlentities to retrieve the data from the database, as that data is already secure. The reason you want to use htmlentities is to make sure user input doesnt contain malicous code such as <script>mess with you tables</script> when you insert it into the DB. URL's need the characters and (I believe) cannot use the HTML entities in the URL.

Comment: That is my company rule so I can't do much about it. But I still have problem with the \" When I insert into database it automatically appear before ". example <a href=\"xxx\">Link</a> How do I remove it?

Comment: When we use htmlentities to insert into DB. and then decode it do the decode can run such script? example: we use htmlentities for prevent <script>, and we decode it. Will the script run?

Comment: @Scramble what supposed to be the output link of your function h?

Comment: You could filter to have the backslashes removed, if thats the only problem you are having. Using htmlentities is escaping the quotes when you're retrieving that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
   $link = h(stripslashes($row['message'])); 
?>


You can click this link <a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'>Link</a>
```